# How to solve espresso test are freezing in emulator?

Tags: android, android-espresso

Eg Filename is LoginUITest.
On my pc, that file is freezing.
But on other pc, the same file is working correctly.
I am using android studio latest version 4.0.1.

Comment: Do you have same emulators on both setups? Do you ran the test from terminal or Android Studios? Any error messages, does it timeout ?

Comment: I run test from android studio. Test are freezing a long time.